# Computing 2 independent models at once leads to wrong results in WinBUGS

Tags: r, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, bugs

I wanted to compare how two different (independent) models perform under winbugs, So I created code like:

```
# likelihood
for (i in 1:sites) {
    M[i] ~ dpois(lambda) # model 1
    M2[i] ~ dpois(lambda2) # model 2

    for (j in 1:sample) {
        obs[i, j] <- sum(y[i, j,])

        # model 1
        y[i, j, 1] ~ dbin(p, M[i])
        obs[i, j] ~ dbin(p_komb, M[i])

        # model 2
        obs[i, j] ~ dbin(p2, M2[i])
    }
}
```

But it leads to wrong results in model 2! But if I separated the model 2:

```
# likelihood
for (i in 1:sites) {
    M2[i] ~ dpois(lambda2)
    for (j in 1:sample) {
        obs[i, j] <- sum(y[i, j,])
        obs[i, j] ~ dbin(p2, M2[i])
    }
}
```

then it performs well and returns good result! I can't really find out why the first example should return different result. The two models combined in the example seems to be completely independent. **WinBUGS bug? Any ideas?**

(It doesn't matter if I separate the models in two for loops 
- result is the same.)

I have WinBUGS 1.4.3 (August 2007) with immortality patch installed.
Here is complete **reproducible code for R and package R2WinBUGS (with data generation)**:

```
################## 
# data generation
require(vcd)

sites <- 120 # 60

mean_M <- 16

M <- rpois(sites, mean_M) 

p <- 0.4 #0.64

sample <- 2 # 3

y = rep(NA, sites * sample * 2)
dim(y) = c(sites, sample, 2)

for (i in 1:sites) {
#   obs[i,] = rbinom(sample, M[i], p)
    for (j in 1:sample) {
        y[i,j,1] = rbinom(1, M[i], p)
        y[i,j,2] = rbinom(1, M[i] - y[i,j,1], p)
    }
}

y_sample_total = apply(y, c(1, 2), sum)

############################################
# two models together - simple model with complex model together 


sink("tmp_bugs/model.txt")
cat("

model {

# likelihood
for (i in 1:sites) {
    M[i] ~ dpois(lambda) # model 1
    M2[i] ~ dpois(lambda2) # model 2

    for (j in 1:sample) {
        obs[i, j] <- sum(y[i, j,])

        # model 1
        y[i, j, 1] ~ dbin(p, M[i])
        obs[i, j] ~ dbin(p_komb, M[i])

        # model 2 (simple)
        obs[i, j] ~ dbin(p2, M2[i])
    }
}

# derived parameters
Mtot <- sum(M[])
M2tot <- sum(M2[])

# priors

tau <- 1/(4 * 4)

p <- 1/(1+exp(-logit_p))
logit_p ~ dnorm(0, tau)

p2 <- 1/(1+exp(-logit_p2))
logit_p2 ~ dnorm(0, tau)

p_komb <- p + (1 - p) * p


lambda ~ dunif(0, 100)
lambda2 ~ dunif(0, 100)

}


")
sink()


win.data = list(y = y, sample = sample, sites = sites)

inits = function () { list(
    M = apply(y_sample_total, 1, max), 
    M2 = apply(y_sample_total, 1, max), 
    logit_p = rnorm(1, 0, 4),
    logit_p2 = rnorm(1, 0, 4)
) }

params = c("M", "M2", "p", "p2", "Mtot", "M2tot", "lambda", "lambda2")
#params = c("M2", "p2", "M2tot", "lambda2")

ni <- 2500
nt <- 16
nb <- 1000
nc <- 3

date()
out1 <- bugs(win.data, inits, params, "model.txt",
    nc, ni, nb, nt, bugs.directory = "C:/Program Files/WinBUGS14/", 
    working.directory = paste(getwd(), "/tmp_bugs/", sep = ""),
    debug = TRUE
)
date()


#############################
# simpler model itself

sink("tmp_bugs/model.txt")
cat("

model {

# likelihood
for (i in 1:sites) {
    M2[i] ~ dpois(lambda2)
    for (j in 1:sample) {
        obs[i, j] <- sum(y[i, j,])
        obs[i, j] ~ dbin(p2, M2[i])
    }
}

# derived parameters
M2tot <- sum(M2[])

# priors

tau <- 1/(4 * 4)

p2 <- 1/(1+exp(-logit_p2))
logit_p2 ~ dnorm(0, tau)

lambda2 ~ dunif(0, 100)

}


")
sink()


win.data = list(y = y, sample = sample, sites = sites)

inits = function () { list(
#   M = apply(y_sample_total, 1, max), 
    M2 = apply(y_sample_total, 1, max), 
#   N = y_sample_total, 
#   after_removal = y[,,2],
#   logit_p = rnorm(1, 0, 4),
#   logit_q = rnorm(1, 0, 4), 
    logit_p2 = rnorm(1, 0, 4)
) }


#params = c("M", "M2", "p", "p2", "Mtot", "M2tot", "lambda", "lambda2")
params = c("M2", "p2", "M2tot", "lambda2")

ni <- 2500
nt <- 16
nb <- 1000
nc <- 3

date()
out2 <- bugs(win.data, inits, params, "model.txt",
    nc, ni, nb, nt, bugs.directory = "C:/Program Files/WinBUGS14/", 
    working.directory = paste(getwd(), "/tmp_bugs/", sep = ""),
    debug = TRUE
)
date()



#############################
# summary - results of simple model (M2, M2tot) differ depending on whether the 
# model was evaluated along with the more complex model or alone!!!
# Shouldn't be!!!

#print(out, dig = 3)

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))

out <- out1

hist(out$sims.list$M2tot, breaks = 100)
abline(v = out$mean$M2tot, col = "red", lwd = 2)
abline(v = sum(M), col = "green", lwd = 2)
#lines(quantile(out$sims.list$M2tot, c(0.025, 0.975)), rep(sum(par("usr")[3:4]*c(0.9,0.1)), 2), lwd = 2)
lines(quantile(out$sims.list$M2tot, c(0.025, 0.975)), rep(par("usr")[3], 2), lwd = 4)
legend("topright", c("estimated total M", "real total M", "95% credible int."), col = c("red", "green", "black"), lty = 1, box.lty = 0, cex = 0.7)

hist(out$sims.list$lambda2)

out <- out2

hist(out$sims.list$M2tot, breaks = 100)
abline(v = out$mean$M2tot, col = "red", lwd = 2)
abline(v = sum(M), col = "green", lwd = 2)
#lines(quantile(out$sims.list$M2tot, c(0.025, 0.975)), rep(sum(par("usr")[3:4]*c(0.9,0.1)), 2), lwd = 2)
lines(quantile(out$sims.list$M2tot, c(0.025, 0.975)), rep(par("usr")[3], 2), lwd = 4)
legend("topright", c("estimated total M", "real total M", "95% credible int."), col = c("red", "green", "black"), lty = 1, box.lty = 0, cex = 0.7)

hist(out$sims.list$lambda2)
```

Comment: Isn't this somehow related to joint probability? But I would suppose that WinBUGS recognizes that the two models are not *"jointed"* in any way and will not *"joint"* them... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have two lines giving a distribution to `obs[i, j]`, and WinBUGS isn't clever enough to figure out that you're trying to do two things at once. The simple solution would be to define distinct variables:

```
    obsa[i, j] <- sum(y[i, j,])
    obsb[i, j] <- sum(y[i, j,])

    # model 1
    obsa[i, j] ~ dbin(p_komb, M[i])

    # model 2
    obsb[i, j] ~ dbin(p2, M2[i])
```

Comment: you are right!!! It is stupid behaviour, because `obs[]` is only derived from data, so it is a fixed number... but he probably takes it as a parameter which then *"joins"* the two models together! Thanks, your fix works, the model 2 is then computed the same way as if separate!

Comment: It also works if you just add `obs2[i, j] <- obs[i, j]` and use `obs` in model 1 and `obs2` in model 2. This is interesting, that pure copy of data makes him think that the data is different. I'd expect the contrary. So suprisingly no need to run the `sum` twice.

Comment: I also tried to supply the obs as input data, already `sum`-ed in R. If I supply only one copy of this data, according to expectation, the behaviour is buggy until I do the same as above, i.e. clone the data by `obs2[i, j] <- obs[i, j]` and use `obs` in model 1 and `obs2` in model 2.