# Prediction based on bayesian model

Tags: bayesian, prediction, jags

I have created a bayesian model that estimates 6 parameters using rjags from R. Now i want to do some predictions based on new data in R. Can anyone help me with an example.

```
model {
   B.m[1] <- Kb # mean B[1]
   B[1] ~ dnorm( B.m[1], tau_B)
   for(t in 2 : 10) { # Process model
      B.m[t]<- max( B[t-1] + rB[t-1](1 -B[t-1]/K) - C[t-1] , 0.0)
      B[t] ~ dnorm(B.m[t], tau_B) } # Observation mode
      for (t in 1: 10) {
         LogC_mean[t] <- log( max(qsegB[t]Eff[t], 0.000001))
         C[t] ~ dlnorm(LogC_mean[t], tau_c) } # Prior
         b~dbeta(1, 1)
         cv <- 1
         K.mean <- 500000
         K.v <- pow(cvK.mean, 2)
         K.tau <- 1/K.v
         K ~ dnorm(K.mean, K.tau)
         r ~ dlnorm(0.0, 1.4)
         qseg ~ dlnorm(-15.4, 1.44)
         tau_c ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
         tau_B ~ dgamma(0.01,0.01)
       }
    }
```

Comment: I just want to understand in general way how to predict new values based on new data from estimated parameters in bayesian framework.

Comment: [Relevant post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31532/how-to-get-prediction-for-a-specific-variable-in-winbugs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, in Bayesian model you do predictions on new data the same way as you do with non-Bayesian models. As your example is complicated I will provide a simplified one to make things easier to illustrate. Say you want to estimate linear regression model

$$ y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \varepsilon_i $$

and based on the model you want to predict $y_\text{new}$ values given $x_\text{new}$ data. In this case you plug in the $x_\text{new}$ into estimated model and JAGS samples $y_\text{new}$ values based on your model. The code would look similar to this:

```
 beta0 ~ dnorm(0, 10)
 beta1 ~ dnorm(0, 10)
 sigma ~ dunif(0, 50)
 for (i in 1:N) {
    y[i] ~ dnorm(beta0 + beta1 * x[i], sigma)
 }
 for (j in 1:Nnew) {
    ynew[j] ~ dnorm(beta0 + beta1 * xnew[j], sigma)
 }
```

where `y`, `x` and `xnew` are data vectors and `ynew` is a variable for storing predictions. What you get is a distribution of values that are plausible given your estimated model. Since the model is probabilistic, the prediction is also probabilistic, i.e. we get the whole distribution of possible `ynew` values. For point-values take the average of `ynew`, you can also make prediction intervals taking the highest density intervals from `ynew` values.

Comment: but in bugs, when you use the symbol ~  you have to provide initial values for this node.

Comment: @AbdelouahedBENMHAMED What node? If some variable (e.g. `beta0` or `ynew`) is 'empty' then the values are just drawn from some distribution. JAGS does the same things with missing values in your data.

Comment: Why do you need "sigma" in "for (j in 1:Nnew) {ynew[j] ~ dnorm(beta0 + beta1 * xnew[j], sigma) }". Will I make a mistake if I do something like this in R (once I obtain beta0 and beta1 from JAGS): "for(j in 1:Nnew) {ynew[j] = beta0 + beta1 * xnew[j] }"?

Comment: @eod it’s a Bayesian model, you want to sample from the posterior predictive distribution.