# rstan: Diagnostics of regression

Tags: regression-coefficients, diagnostic, stan

I ran a simple normal regression in rstan with some informative priors. My data has heteroskedasticity and would like to fix the same. However, I am new to bayesian regression and rstan. My questions are

1. Can I use the mean of the estimates of coefficients for forecasting out of sample?
2. How do I find the standard error of my regression? Can I still do $\sigma^2 (X'X)^{-1}$?
3. Can I just plot the result of the residuals of regression against fitted values to see the test for heteroskedasticity?

Comment: Why do you want to use Bayesian linear regression if you want to use it *exactly the same* as frequentist linear regression?

Comment: what is frequentist linear regression? I can't run a robust regression with trimmed outliers as fat tails are not outliers here.

Comment: @Tim OP said they have informative priors

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can I use the mean of the estimates of coefficients for forecasting out of sample?

You could, but why?  A big selling point of Bayesian modelling is the ability to integrate over uncertainty in the parameters.  You would do this by generating from the *posterior predictive distribution*, namely

$$ p(\tilde{y} \vert y) = \int p(\tilde{y}\vert \theta) p(\theta \vert y) d \theta $$

This integral can be approximated by taking estimates of your coefficients and generating data via the likelihood.  In Stan, you might right a linear regression and posterior predictive quantities as

```
data{
    int n;
    int p;
    vector[n] y;
    matrix[n, p] X;
}
parameters{
  vector[p] beta;
  real<lower=0> sigma;
}
model{
  beta ~ <priors_here>;
  sigma ~ <priors_here>;
  y ~ normal(X*b, sigma);
}
generated quantities{
  //Here is the posterior predictive
  vector[n] y_tilde;
  for(i in 1:n){
    y_tilde[i] = normal_rng(X*b, sigma);
  }
}
```

For each sample, Stan will compute `X*b` and then draw a gaussian random vairable with mean `X*b` and standard deviation `sigma`.  If you average each of these, then you get a prediction for each row in `X`.

> 2. How do I find the standard error of my regression?

Uncertainty in the parameters can be obtained directly from the samples outputted by Stan.

> 3. can I just plot the result of the residuals of regression against fitted values to see the test for heteroskedasticity?

That is certainly one way to check the model.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is answered in the [Prediction based on bayesian model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147921/prediction-based-on-bayesian-model/147926#147926) thread. Notice that you can make two different kinds of predictions: you can predict the distribution of outcome and the point estimate. If you need a point estimate than you can take mean, median, mode (i.e. [maximum a posteriori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) estimate) etc., depending on your needs.

As about standard errors, what kind of errors do you need and what for? With Bayesian model you will obtain posterior distribution of your parameters and [posterior predictive distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution) of your outcome. With those distributions you can easily obtain interval estimates (see [credible intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240749/how-to-find-95-credible-interval/240777#240777)). In fact Bayesian credible intervals give you much more information about the distribution of your outcomes then confidence intervals [as discussed in here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184163/what-can-we-conclude-from-a-bayesian-credible-interval/184417#184417).